# Can I store a custom variable in a quote? (temporarily) M1.9.2.4

Tags: event-observer, quote, variables

In Magento, can I store a custom variable in a quote? (temporarily)

We use an observer for quote item ... but I need to store a variable in the qupte to use later .... this cannot be used sales/session of customer/session - must be in quote

help appreciated

Comment: Which magento version?

Comment: did you see the update? is this version dependent?

Comment: To some extent, yes, but, When is "later" ?